# Reposition a view using GeometryReader3D

Tags: swiftui, visionos

I want to be position a SwiftUI view in visionOS that is not at the feet of the user (ground zero) but in front of the user at eye level.

In this WWDC video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10111/), they reposition a RealityKit model to that location but I want to do so with a SwiftUI view with an image (below) or text. The following does not work:

```
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "Example") {
        GeometryReader3D { proxy in
            Image("Red Panda")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 1000)
                .position(centerPoint)
                .onAppear {
                    if let translation = proxy.transform(in: .global)?.translation {
                        self.centerPoint = Point3D(translation)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    .immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.full), in: .mixed, .full)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.offset(..)` modifier to specify the values ​​for Z and Y coordinates in points.

```
import SwiftUI

@main struct YourApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "Immersion") {
            GeometryReader3D { proxy in
                Image("appleLogo")
                    .offset(z: proxy.size.depth - 3000)
                    .offset(y: proxy.size.height - 2700)
            }
        }
        .immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.full), in: .mixed, .full)
    }
}
```

[image]